# Extjs 6 store pass value php

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I am trying to pass a value from the store to php before the store is loaded. Extjs 4 allows me to use:

store: Ext.getStore('survey.store.Comments').load({params:{employee: record.get('employee')}}),

But in Extjs 6 I get **TypeError: Ext.getStore(...) is undefined**

I have also tried

```
 store:{
 type: 'myComment',
 autoLoad: true,
 autoDestroy: true,
 params:{
     employee: record.get("employee")
 }
```

and I get **Undefined index: employee in /var/www/html/survey/myComment.php**

Comment: Depending on your implementation you can pass values using the proxy config of the store. To help you in a proper way, please create a fiddle or share more code.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working and yes, I used proxy

Comment: Why don't you tell us how you got it working and mark the question as resolved then?

Comment: proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                      extraParams:{
                              employee: record.get("employee")
                       }
             }